# Как сделать открытие двух id?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такие кнопки на телефоне, когда их нажимаешь, должно по якорной ссылке открывать соответствующий пункт в прайсе, но из-за того что кнопка скрывает прайс по id это не получается сделать. А при нажатии на кнопку, открывается полный прайс.
У кнопок на телефоне href="prays1"..href="prays2"...href="prays13"

```css
[id^="all"] {
position: fixed; /* чтобы страница "не подпрыгивала" к id */
}
[id^="all"]:target + table a[href^="#all"],
[id^="all"]:not(:target) + table tbody tr:nth-of-type(n+4), /* 4 — это порядковый номер tr, после которого строки будут изначально удалены (включительно) */
[id^="all"]:not(:target) + table a[href="#close"] {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<p  id="all1"/></p>
<table class="demotable">
<thead>
<tr>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#all1" style="margin-top:200px"><button style="background-color: #0073A4;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(41, 41, 41, 0.86);
    padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;border:none;color:white;margin-top:10px;">Смотреть все цены</button></a>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th id="prays1">Замена дисплейного модуля
<td>от 35р
<td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
<tr>
<th  id="prays2">Замена стекла дисплейного модуля
<td>от 10р
<td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
<tr>
  <tr>
  <th>Замена дисплейного модуля
  <td>от 10р
  <td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
<tr>
    <tr>
    <th 
id="prays3">Перепрошивка/обновление/восстановление ПО
    <td>от 10р
    <td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
<tr>
      <tr>
      <th  id="prays4">Чистка от пыли/влаги
      <td>от 10р
      <td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
      <tr>
        <tr>
              <tr>
              <th  id="prays5">Установка навигационных карт
              <td>от 10р
              <td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
              <tr>
                <tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th  id="prays6">Замена корпуса
                      <td>от 10р
                      <td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
                      <tr>
                        <tr>
                              <tr>
                              <th>Замена шлейфа кнопки включения
                              <td>от 10р
                              <td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
                              <tr>
                                <tr>
                                      <tr>
                                      <th>Замена стекла камеры (основной)
                                      <td>от 10р
                                      <td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
                                      <tr>
                                        <tr>
                                              <tr>
                                              <th>Замена кнопки Home
                                              <td>от 10р
                                              <td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
                                              <tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                      <th>Замена вибромотора
                                                      <td>от 10р
                                                      <td class="popmake-726" style="text-decoration: underline;">заказать ремонт
                        </table>
```